# How we can access External content type to client system via code?

Tags: sharepoint-server, bcs

In visual studio we are creating one project and implement some functionality. Then we are deploying in bin folder we can get .wsp file.

So the same functionality need for our client or other system means we should deploy the .wsp on client system.so the same functionality will work on client system.

Now my doubt is that how we can implement External content type?

For example in my system I have created one database in SQL server,In SharePoint designer I have created External Content type.Then the SQL data are display in SharePoint List.

This same functionality I need to implement in client system.But I don't want to do this manually, how we can implement it via code?

How we can install .wsp in client system same functionality work on client system like that? how can we achieve this External Content type Functionality using **c#** or power shell or REST API and any other script language.

How we can get client system SQL database through code and how we can show database details in SharePoint list ?

What I need is **how to Create BCS service application programmatically**?

I searched in google but every article is in SharePoint designer only they are creating external content type.
please someone give some idea for this.

In central admin  I need to add BDC programmatically.
[image]
[image]
[image]

When I will create external list in select external content type I will add SQL Database from client system.

Comment: You can create BCS service application using Central Admin. Why you want to choose the hard way? Check this URL https://melcher.it/2013/01/powershell-create-the-bdc-service-application-for-sharepoint-2013/

Comment: Our requirement is programmatically we can get sql databases from client system and add BDC to central admin its possible ?

Comment: Yes it is possible. SharePoint provides very rich API to handle all these use cases.

Comment: can you please For this requirement any sample code or share any link.

Comment: For example client they are having 50 different databases with different name in SQL 50 database we should connect to BDC. So i need to create 50 bdc model in visual studio ?
I was very confused how i can get databases from Sql and How i can connect that database to BDC. ?
Can you please give some idea and share any link ?

Comment: I edited my question please give some idea to how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

From your dev system you can export External Content Types and import it in client system.

After import you can open the external system and update SQL server information.

Comment: How and where we can import ,exported external content type.
In central admin Bdc service no option for import ?

Comment: Check this http://www.manula.com/manuals/lightning-tools/bcs-meta-man-for-windows/1/en/topic/importing-the-bdc-model-into-sharepoint

Comment: we are creating BDC  in SP Designer there only we can create the list.But after import the ETC in central admin how we can add the ETC to SharePoint List.

Comment: You can either manually create the list after ECT import or you can create a feature in Visual Studio and use it to create the list on activation.

Comment: can you please share any link for this ?

Comment: https://habaneroconsulting.com/insights/creating-an-external-list-programmatically#.VzM2zEaXeJI